# Why is this function not visible inside this _.each loop?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

`function setPanodata()` prepares a `panodata` before it is save:

```
          if (confirm('Are you sure you want to update this?')) {
            var query = new AV.Query('PanoramaData')
            query.equalTo('roomModelId', currentPanoId)
            query.find().then(function(avpds) {
              var addedAVs = []
              var unsavedPDs = []
              var unchangedPDs = _.filter(avpds, function(avpd) {
                return _.find(scope.panodatas, {
                  objectId: avpd.id
                })
              })
              _.each(unchangedPDs, function(unchangedPD) {
                // Offset x and y before save
                unchangedPD.set('x', offsetX(scope.panodatas[unchangedPD.get('index')].x))
                unchangedPD.set('y', offsetY(scope.panodatas[unchangedPD.get('index')].y))
                unsavedPDs.push(unchangedPD)
              })
              var addedPds = _.filter(scope.panodatas, function(pd) {
                return !pd.objectId
              })
              _.each(addedPds, function(point) {
                var Panodata = AV.Object.extend('PanoramaData')
                var panodata = new Panodata()
                addedAVs.push(setPanodata(panodata))
              })
              unsavedPDs = unsavedPDs.concat(addedAVs)
              console.log(unsavedPDs)
              saveAllPanodatas(unsavedPDs)
            })
          }

          function setPanodata(panodata) {
            panodata.set('index', point.index)
            panodata.set('x', offsetX(point.x))
            panodata.set('y', offsetY(point.y))
            panodata.set('roomModelId', scope.pano.id)
            panodata.set('panoDataRotate', 0)
            panodata.set('differentLayout', false)
            panodata.set('panoCount', 6)
            panodata.set('type', 'VRoom')
            console.log('PANODATA', panodata)
            return panodata
          }
```

Initially, I placed its content inside  `_.each(addedPds, function(point) {` but decided to turn it into a function to make the code cleaner.

However, `console.log('PANODATA', panodata)` doesn't log anything. So `setPanodata()` is not visible inside `_.each(addedPds, function(point) {`

Why is this?

Comment: try window.setPanodata(panodata) inside your each

Comment: If `setPanodata` was not visible inside `_.each` and it got called, you would get an error. (You did check for an error in the console, I assume.) Instead, check that your `_.each` is executing, and that `addedPds` is not empty by logging `addedPds` just before the loop.

Comment: `doesn't log anything` - therefore the _.each loop isn't being executed, because that would log at least `'PANODATA', undefined` if panodata was undefined

Comment: your `_.filter` will only return `scope.panodatas` WITHOUT an `objectID` - is that correct?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before `_.each()` and check the value of `addedPds`.

Comment: I'll bet `addedPds` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setPanodata uses point, but you are not passing point into the function. Try this instead:

```
 _.each(addedPds, function(point) {
     var Panodata = AV.Object.extend('PanoramaData');
     var panodata = new Panodata();
     addedAVs.push(setPanodata(panodata, point));
 });

 function setPanodata(panodata, point) {
    panodata.set('index', point.index)
    panodata.set('x', offsetX(point.x))
    panodata.set('y', offsetY(point.y))
    panodata.set('roomModelId', scope.pano.id)
    panodata.set('panoDataRotate', 0)
    panodata.set('differentLayout', false)
    panodata.set('panoCount', 6)
    panodata.set('type', 'VRoom')
    console.log('PANODATA', panodata)
    return panodata
 }
```

Comment: So? The problem is that `setPanodata` is never even being called.

Comment: How do we know it's not being called? The function is visible, but would not log anything because it would error not knowing about point.

Comment: Why wouldn't it log anything? If `point` is undefined, there would be an error message about trying to get the `index` property of undefined.

Comment: `point` is presumably a variable declared in an outer scope, so it doesn't need to be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Isn't `point` the objects in `addedPds` that the function isbeing applied? Also, there would be an error in the log, but nothing from the console.log call.

Comment: You're right. And I didn't notice that he has the `console.log()` at the end of the function instead of the beginning.

Comment: Can you edit your answer, showing the correct way to code this, so I can remove my downvote and add an upvote?